# Reverse ball direction in canvas animation

Tags: canvas, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to reverse my animation once it reaches certain point using the code bellow, the thing is that i'm using setinterval to call the animation function and once the condition is met to start reversing it executes again and freezes the ball what should I do how can I bypass that?

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 3
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 0;
var reverse = -2

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();

  if (x == 290) {
    x += reverse
  } else {
    x += dx
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a variable to control the direction could do what you need with the least amount of changes to your current code:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var startX = canvas.width / 3;
var x = startX;
var y = canvas.height - 30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 0;
var reverse = -2
var isForward = true;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();

  if (x > 290) {
    isForward = false;
  }
  if (x < startX) {
    isForward = true;
  }

  x = isForward ? ++x : --x;
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I would suggest a few changes to your script. Mainly using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` will improve performance and ensure you have a smooth animation. Then using some ES6 features that help to understand how the value of the variables will be handled, `const` for values that don't change over time and `let` for those that the value changes. There is also `speed` to tune how fast the ball moves:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const startX = canvas.width / 3;
let x = startX;
let y = canvas.height - 30;
const dx = 2;
const dy = 0;
let isForward = true;
const speed = 1.5

const drawBall = () => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
const clear = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
const updateCoordinates = () => {
  if (x > 290) {
    isForward = false;
  } else if (x < startX) {
    isForward = true;
  }

  x = isForward ? x + speed : x - speed;
}

const animationLoop = () => {
  updateCoordinates();
  clear();
  drawBall();

  // call next frame...
  requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```